# movement of knight in a game of chess

Tags: combinatorics

This question arose in my brain while playing a game of chess. We all know how a knight moves in a game of chess. I wanted to calculate the minimum no. of moves required by a knight to cover all the 64 squares of the chess board. I didn't know how to proceed to calculate this. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by knight "covering" squares? Do you mean knight visiting every square? If so, then you mean this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour

Comment: Is the answer $64-1$?  A knight only moves to one square at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start with a night on a square, it will take you exactly 63 moves. This is called the Knights tour. There is a very detailed [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ab_dY3dZFHM) describing Knight's tour. But to answer your question: 63 moves.

Comment: (Though, if the starting position counts as a "move," that'd make it 64.)